# Deleting checked ListView items

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I'm trying to delete `ListView` items that are checked. It works if there is only one item checked but if there are two or three then the app force closes. On the error log it says:

> E/AndroidRuntime(2173): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 2, size is 2

When having three items on the list and deleting 2. Can anyone help with correcting this error? Here is the code:

```
    public void delete() {
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View view = list.getChildAt(i);

                 CheckedTextView cv = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkList);
                 if(cv.isChecked()){
                    Log.i("DELETE", adapter.getItem(i).toString()+"   "+cv.toString());

                     adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
                 }
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Items Cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your for loop. you are iterating list view in the for loop by `list.getChildCount()` which is not correct read the Api doc correctly, replace it with `adapter.getCount();` it will solve the problem.

Comment: This did help but now if there are 5 items and the first two (0 and 1)are checked; positions 0 and 2 get deleted, leaving 1, 3, and  4.
I know what is happening but not sure how to correct it.

Comment: If 0 and 1 positions are checked. In the loop, 1 becomes 0 after 0 is deleted causing 2 to be deleted the second time leaving 1.

Comment: OK fixed, i had to adjust the lop to start deleting from the bottom up the list, working towards the top or 0. this is what i change it to, " for (int i = adapter.getCount()-1; i !=-1 ; i--) "

Comment: Still some bug when items are added to list will update code when figured out. but this problem has been solved.

Comment: Incredible how hard it is to delete checked items of a list in Android.