# How to remove checked items from listview and in database

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi i want to remove the checked items from the listview and in database.Iam using menus for that.If delete is selected from the menu then i want to remove the selected items from the listview and in the database.If select all is clicked in the menu i want to set all the checkbox of the listitems checked and then delete all the values from the listview and to delete all the records in the database.Iam using the following code to populate the data from the database in the listview with checkbox.Please help me if anybody knows.

Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.senthistory);               
        lvhistory = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);     
        PopulateSentList();             
    }

    public void PopulateSentList() {

        String strquery = "SELECT * FROM sent_history";
        Cursor Cursor = (MainscreenActivity.JEEMAAndroSMSDB).rawQuery(
                strquery, null);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(SentHistoryActivity.this, Cursor);
        setListAdapter(adapter);    
        lvhistory.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SQLiteCursor selectedValue = (SQLiteCursor) getListAdapter()
                        .getItem(position);
                String id1 = selectedValue.getString(0);
                System.out.println("DATA-->>>" + id1);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Historydisplay.class);
                intent.putExtra("Id", id1);
                final int result = 1;
                startActivityForResult(intent, result);
            }           
        });
    }


    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(SentHistoryActivity.this,
                MainscreenActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void CreateMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.setQwertyMode(true);
        MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Delete");
        {
            mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('D');
        }
        MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Select All");
        {
            mnu2.setAlphabeticShortcut('S');
        }
    }

    private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item) throws Exception {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            int count = (int) getListAdapter().getCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                if (this.lvhistory.isItemChecked(i)) {
                    listItems.remove(i);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    MainscreenActivity.JEEMAAndroSMSDB.delete(
                            MainscreenActivity.Table_SentHistory, "_id=" +i, null); 
                    finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SentHistoryActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        CreateMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        try {
            return MenuChoice(item);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }       

    private class MyAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor cur) {
            super(context, R.layout.dummy, cur);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cur, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            return li.inflate(R.layout.dummy, parent, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) {
            TextView tvListText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Mobile);
            final CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.check);            

            tvListText.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MainscreenActivity.COL_Mobile)));
            chkBox.setTag(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MainscreenActivity.COL_Sent_id))); 

            chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.v("Checked", chkBox.getTag().toString());                      
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removing checked items you can use isChecked() method for CheckBox. In your code you can use in following manner.

```
    chkBox.setOnClickListener(new new OnClickListener() {               
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v;

            if(cb.isChecked() == true)
             { 
                  String getStrinValue = cb.getTExt().toString(); // here you will get the value of selected CheckBox
                     //  And now you have to perform your deletion operation as usual.                
              }
   }
```

Comment: I want to remove the data which is selected by choosing Delete from the menu.How can i do like that.Iam new to android.Please help me in such a way.

Comment: @user1498488 I have made some changes in my post please find it.Good luck :)

Comment: Sorry to say akshay, i dont know what to do further to delete the selected items by selecting the delete menu.If u have free time means then please guide me to do like that.

Comment: @user1498488 I will suggest you please read this post for using database this might help you.If you don't get then let me know. http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/database-crud-tutorial-for-android/

Comment: I make the above snippet worked for me.Thanks a lot.But a little change String getStrinValue = cb.getTag().toString().

Comment: Could u tell me how to check all the items inside a bindview? I mean if i choose select all from menu i want check all the items of the list.How can i achieve this? Is there any possibilities for that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14855/discussion-between-akshay-and-user1498488)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i'll give an overview of how to accomplish. This is what i did for my application.

First you need to have a model class for the list item which has a property to maintain the state(checked), then whenever you are getting the items from the database create list of items, such as arraylist.

Then whenever the check box get checked change the state property of the particular list item. Finally when you click the delete from the menu, there would be three steps

1. Get the checked items from the arraylist
2. Remove items from the adapter
3. Remove items from the database

I think this would make sense

**EDIT**

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418764/deleting-checked-listview-items?rq=1) previous SO question? BTW this will help only to remove the items from the adapter. You have to find a way to remove the items from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i did. I found this to be the easiest solution to always match the right ID. Because the adapter and the cursor will always have the same counting and position. Both have a starting index at 0.

This is what's inside my case for the menu item.
I also added an alert dialog as a safety step.

```
    if (mListView.getCount() == 0 || mListView.getCheckedItemCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Select an item by holding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete these items?");
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    builder.setPositiveButton(
        "Yes",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                SparseBooleanArray selection = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                Cursor data = mDBHandler.getAllIDs(); // "SELECT " + COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
                int itemID;
                int itemCount = arrayAdapter.getCount();
                for (int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (selection.get(i)) {
                        data.moveToPosition(i);
                        itemID = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id")); // COLUMN_ID = "id"
                        mDBHandler.deleteItem(itemID);
                    }
                }
                selection.clear();
                updateListView();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

    builder.setNegativeButton(
        "No",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDelete = builder.create();
    alertDelete.show();
    return true;


public void updateListView() {
    mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    Cursor data = mDBHandler.getItems();
    arrayList.clear();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        arrayList.add(data.getString(1));
    }
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```